# Getting a Type variable knowing the name of type C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm developing a `TypeTranslator` class which has a method `Type TranslateType(Type type)`.
This method gets a type of an interface and if there's a class of interface name without leading I  it creates it, otherwise an exception is raised.
Here's some code to clearify what's written before:

```
class Program
{
    interface IAnimal { }
    class Animal : IAnimal { }
```

```
void Function()
{
    TypeTranslator typeTranslator = new TypeTranslator();
    Assert(typeTranslator.TranslateType(typeof(IAnimal) == typeof(Animal)));
}
```

}

Is it possible to get what I want?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `Type.GetType`. The documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get a type name from a string variable? If yes, then you can use [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method. Of course, the method expects the type name to be qualified by its namespace. Alternatively, if you don't want to restrict the type to a specific namespace, you can grab all types in an assembly with [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) method and look for a type with a specific name.

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard about [**dependeny injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dependency+injection)? Maybe this is exactly what you need ...

See [what is dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) and maybe on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) for more infos, too.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at `Object.GetType()`, `Assembly.GetTypes()` (using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, for example) , `Type.IsClass`, `Type.IsInterface`, `Type.Name` (which is like `FullName` but without the full qualifier) and the `Activator` class to create an instance. 
It's basically getting all types, looping over them, checking whether they are class types and whether their name is the one of the interface.